# My function in C reads and parses data from stdin to store in members of a struct. How can it read in the next part of input each time it is called?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stdin, fgets

The struct is defined in the header file **instance.h** like this:

```
typedef struct instance{
    char *a;
    char *b;
    int c
} Instance;
```

I have a function: 
**Instance *get_instance(FILE *fd)** 
in the file instance.c that reads data from stdin and parses it into the members a, b and c in a struct Instance.

I use:

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, fd) != NULL && (nlines != 4))
```

to read 4 lines from stdin and parse it into char arrays and an int.

The input from stdin has the format:

```
instance1 info
instance1 info
instance1 info
instance1 info
instance2 info
instance2 info
instance2 info
instance2 info
... and so on
```

This is why I read in 4 lines only to be parsed.

I call this function in main.c:

```
Instance *ip;
while ((ip = get_instance(stdin)) != NULL) {
// print info in ip
}
```

I want it to print instance1 info and then instance2 info, then instance3 info and so on...

But, when get_instance is invoked again in the while, it prints out the instance1 info repeatedly.

Is there a way for the get_instance function to "remember" the place it last read up to -- namely the 4th line -- and read this time from line 5?

Comment: It's difficult to understand you. Can you try to explain it in a more clear way?. And post teh contents of `get_instance`.

Comment: Please post **get_instance's definition** so that we may further analyze the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  get/save all input from stdin first before you loop get_instance().

My guess (without actual get_instance() implementation) the problem is calling the fgets() loop within the get_instance() loop.   And get_instance() can't handle that.